# How to backup Whatsapp images proparly?

Tags: backup, whatsapp-messenger, google-photos

I bought a new phone (OnePlus Nord 2 5G) and to my surprise, the WhatsApp backup restore my images but without dates.

I think the best solution for backing up images is to drop WhatsApp backup (for images only) and use Google Photos backup as I did for my camera images.

I saw a way to disable WhatsApp images backup which involved renaming the images folder but I am not sure what consequences this will have.

Any idea? how do you guys back up your WhatsApp images?

Answer (score 0):

I use [Wifi FTP Server](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.medhaapps.wififtpserver&hl=en_GB&gl=US) on my Android device with [FreeFileSync](https://freefilesync.org/) on my laptop to backup any files I need.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thanks! This is so fustrating when u use those big companies software and all those features are just f-ed up. U can't even disable image backup in WhatsApp, this is so basic!